# Any formula for this series $\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there a formula for calculating this series:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i^2}
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Gerry's answer a little, you'll get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_3(0,x)+1)
$$
See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) (Eqn. 3) for more.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's a partial sum of a theta series, q.v.