# Finding the sum of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{ai^2+bi+c}$

Tags: summation, power-series

I'm trying to find a closed form for $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{ai^2+bi+c}$.

I'm thinking I might be able to use the geometric sum for a polynomial of one less degree, $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{ai+b} = \frac{r^{b}}{1-r^{a}}(1-(r^{a})^{n+1})$, because the second degree polynomial contains the first degree polynomial $r^{ai^2+bi+c}=r^{i(ai+b)}r^{c}$.

I've also tried completing the square:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{ai^2+bi+c} = r^{c-\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{a(i+\frac{b}{2a})^{2}}$

But then it seems like I need to solve a sum similar to $\sum_{j=0}^{n}r^{j^2}$

Comment: Related [Any formula for this series $\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114329/any-formula-for-this-series-sum-i-0n-xi2)

Comment: FWIW Mathematica gives no closed form solution, not to say that means there isn't one, however. But it's probably not easy...

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{ax^2+bx+c}=(n+1)r^{ax^2+bx+c}$ :p

Comment: I did it because having an integer index denoted by $x$ is very strange.!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the edit. I figured seeing the polynomial in terms of x might be more familiar than seeing it in terms of i, but I agree. Summation in terms of x is a strange sight.